# Solaris or Centos?

Tags: centos, solaris, web

This is probably a broad question. I have used CentOS a lot, but never tried Solaris.

My company needs to set up 4 new web servers to host PHP web applications (with an external MSSQL database server). I think it is a chance to ask this question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this type of questions is not easy.

In general, you can use the following criteria,

1- When comparing free and commercial products, you have two cases: no support (you will be on your own) and supported product. I am not sure if you are talking about free or commercial here!

2- When you have knowledge and experience in one product over the other, yous should prefer the one you know better. Otherwise, you need to spend time and efforts to learn the new product to be able to secure it properly and avoid the common pitfalls, etc.. So, this gives Centos +1.

3- When you have old/previous systems and network, it may be better to stick with the same OS/environment when applicable. This will make managing your resources easier and in a uniform manner. Of course, you should avoid this option if you find a certain drawback or shortcoming in your current environment.

Comment: 1, Free one. Sorry didn't make it clear. 2, Good point. 3, OK then. Thanks. Centos then. The reason I was thinking about this is Solaris is UNIX, so that I can get some UNIX server working experience. I guess I am trying to add value to my future career. UNIX admins paid more... :)

Comment: I think jumping onto a different OS for production purposes is a bit cavalier (unless you are using Solaris servers elsewhere in your organisation. Do run OpenIndiana in your home lab (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenIndiana) and then setup a 'development' machine at work. Then you can start figuring out where Solaris might help at work. You might need/want expensive hardware :-)

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I have been using Centos a lot, but
>   never try Solaris.

That means there really can only be one answer. Use CentOS for your current needs. If you see a justification for exploring Solaris, do that as well as some smaller side-project, and then, after you're comfortable with it, consider it for production.

Answer (score 1):

ZFS and Zones makes it worth looking at Solaris, but I wouldn't put something into production until you're familiar with it.  The open source offshoot of Solaris is available as Open Indiana: http://openindiana.org/

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not experiment on servers, that will be exposed directly to the Internet.

So you should stick with CentOS.

You also mention PHP. Php works almost everywhere, but its primary system is linux, most help, howto's, guides etc. you will find are for linux hosting, so for that alone you should favor linux.

Answer (score -2):

Solaris is probably too open answer, so CentOS. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I would Choose Linux, so CentOS, because with yum or apt-get you can put a server into production in no-time. I like Zend Server CE, it is very fast because and it is optimized and on Solaris is not supported. I prefect Open Source instead of commercial products. PHP on Solaris it is not well documented.

I fully suscribe to Khaled list :-)